# powerplant model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

```
// This will make the model the correct size, but cause the mdoel to
// rotate. The powerplant model is a good example.
```

Where do we get the powerplant model? :) It doesn't seem to be in the repository.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20/powerplant-model/) by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 508 on 2012-09-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This comment was in error, and has been removed from the repository. Sorry for the confusion.

The powerplant model will appear next week in the new model database.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0